# Colorbox does not group images

Tags: yii, colorbox

I'm using [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) in form of [Yii 1.x widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jcolorbox). Everything works fine, except for the fact, that Colorbox does not group my images and does not show `<--` / `-->` buttons.

This is part of code generated by my page:

```
<div class="media-gallery-wrapper">

    <div class="media-gallery-item">

        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/usrector/htdocs/uploads/galleries/15.jpg" class="colorbox cboxElement" title="">

            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/usrector/htdocs/uploads/galleries/15small.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="450">

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

Each three of such blocks are followed by:

```
<div class="media-gallery-separator"></div>
```

And that's all. Even though I've been trying to modify my code and browsing through Colorbox examples, I don't see any significant difference between my code and those on [examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/). Thus, I don't know, what makes my Colorbox not grouping images?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping in Colorbox works **only**, if you base it on `rel` attribute. You can't use classes.

So, this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>" class="colorbox" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.colorbox').colorbox({'maxHeight':'80%','maxWidth':'90%'});
</script>
```

won't work (no image grouping, no `<-` / `->` buttons), while this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>" rel="colorbox" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('a[rel="colorbox"]').colorbox({'maxHeight':'80%','maxWidth':'90%'});
</script>
```

will work like a charm.